# Image resizing and interpolation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In digital image processing, I need to understand what does image resizing do? Does it only change the dimensions of the image, for example, from 256×256 to 128×128 with the same pixel spacing (the same dpi)? Or does it change the dpi or pixel spacing in an image? If I need to increase the size of the image and also increase its dpi, how can I do this?

Comment: DPI and pixel spacing are physical properties of the display, not the image itself.

Comment: @beaker: I'd rather say that it is the "intended" reproduction size of the image. Either it corresponds to the resolution of the scanner that digitized the document, or it is assigned by a CAD software when working with world dimensions. A smart display device could then resize the image to adjust to its own DPI.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure, but those uses imply some sort of metadata associated with the image, which MATLAB doesn't support.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually, my previous (now deleted) comment was a bit flippant. I expect that, rather than nonsense, this is more of an XY-problem.

Answer (score 2):

The DPI information is somewhat immaterial. It describes the pixel size in physical coordinates, hence only makes sense when you input an image (from a scanner or a camera) or output it (to a screen, a projector or a printer).

In the case of a camera or a projector, the pixel size is unknown as it depends on the viewing distance. In other cases, it may be honored or not depending on if the device is calibrated and cares about the DPI value, and if the physical image size allows it. (For example, a printer may automatically resize the image to fit it on the page.)

In addition, if you use an image resizing software, it could be that this software does not update the DPI information at all, or even sets a fixed value.

In virtually all cases, image resizing is understood as changing the number of pixels, and requires interpolation in case of magnification. It does transform the image, in particular its storage size, and impacts every pixel. On the other hand, changing the DPI is a mere modification of a numerical parameter associated to the image.

Actually, there is no unique answer to your request. Depending on the intent and desired effect, resizing the image may involve changing the number of pixels, changing the DPI, or both.

Comment: Interpolation is required even when making the image smaller, as long as there's not a 1:1 correspondence between input and output size.

Comment: It all depends on how you define "interpolation".  Proper software will use a larger interpolation kernel as the output gets smaller.  Certainly there's lots of improper software out there, and the naive interpolator that just uses the nearest neighbors will get it wrong.

Comment: I'm not asking you to change anything. I'm just pointing out a simple fact. If you look at the code to implement filtering vs. interpolation you won't see much difference. Mathematically they are the same.

Comment: @MarkRansom: the two terms *interpolation* and *approximation* exist and correspond to different concepts. Subsampling by interpolation works poorly.

Comment: My definition of "interpolation" is not as rigid as yours. Again, look at the math that implements it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ok, these terms were introduced by mistake.